# Узнать сколько прошло времени с выхода из игры, даже если пользователь поменял дату

Tags: c#, unity3d, datetime

Хочу узнать прошел ли час при нажатии, допустим, на кнопку. Знаю, что можно узнать время нажатия и отнять текущее время. Но пользователь может подкрутить время через надстройки.

Можно ли узнать, допустим, менялась ли дата. Игра оффлайн. Буду очень признателен. Видел, что во многих играх это уже автоматизировано.

Comment: это https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html ?

Comment: Нет, это работает только когда игра на паузе. А мне нужно что бы при неактивной игре считать время, только вот что бы нельзя было подкрутить

Comment: Способ слегка топорный, использовал в своих проектах, но они были некоммерческими.
При первом запуске приложения сохранял текущую дату в PlayerPrefs. Ну и при последующих включениях просто считал разницу и тоже записывал ее в сохранение. Если при каком-либо запуске разница была отрицательной, либо меньше той, которая уже записана, то в блок. Подкрутить в таком случае можно, но гораздо сложнее.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить, что если вообще без подключения к интернету, то надежного способа нет. Игра может быть оффлайн, но выделите местечко под один онлайн запрос, который берет время с сервера. И при любом запуске приложения при включенном интернете время будет сверяться с реальным, а не подкрученным.

Comment: Да я уже понял это, уже пишу запрос через PHP. Но вот про то что ты написал ранее у меня такая же мысль была в голове но всё же  подкрутить можно допустим мне надо активировать возможность на один час, а тут 59 минут времени что бы дернуть назад время. Даже пускай это муторная работа но вот такая возможность есть и это печаль чел просто устанет и пойдет спать

Comment: Ещё раз скажу, в оффлайне надежных решений нет. А зачем вам PHP? Чтобы время возвращать? Я в таких случаях не изобретаю велосипед и пользуюсь яндексом - https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213, это время для Москвы в эпохальном формате, ну и ещё погода бонусом))

Comment: Через php, я получаю дату с сервера(в FTP создаю .php пишу один запрос строкой например <?php echo date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");?>), после уже беру ссылку этой страницы и считываю поле, но вашь вариант очень удобен спасибо

Comment: Если это игра, то она должна рисовать какие то кадры, обрабатывать пользовательский ввод. И скорее всего фпс будет какой то плюс-минус стабильный. Вот просто считаем кадры, а также время от времени фпс.Зная фпс и кол-во кадров, можно очень неплохо посчитать время. Если в процессе подсчетов фпс, кол-во кадров сильно прыгает (а то и отрицательное) - опа, поймали за руку.